# LSTM layer (keras) is causing all layers after it to constantly predicting the same thing no matter the input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, ocr

I have a model for OCR, and I came to realise that after 2-3 epochs the output of the model is the same. So when I predicted values and looked at the output for each layer I realised that all layers after the 1st layer in the LSTM block output the same values no matter the output. So here is the model (or the parts related to the problem):

```
Processing = layers.Reshape((12,9472))(encoder)

Processing = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(Processing)

lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences = True))(Processing)
lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True))(lstm)
lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences = True))(lstm)

outputs = layers.Dense(358,activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(lstm)
outputs = layers.Dense(358, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(outputs)
outputs = layers.Dense(l, activation='softmax',name='output')(outputs)

output = CTCLayer()(labels,outputs)
```

Everything after (and including) the 1st LSTM layer outputs the same value (not including the CTC layer thing due to it being removed for predictions).

Before picking the model apart I thought it may have been a dying relu problem so I replaced all of the activation functions which where relu with the leaky relu. So what is causing this is there something wrong with my implementation? or what may be causing the everything after the LSTM layer to "die". How would I fix the underlying issue?

FYI: the CTCLayer is the one from the code example from the keras website

BTW: Another weird thing is that even after it outputs the same thing the loss values reduce for some time (so from 20.5 - 16.2), so its still learning. Im pretty sure it has nothing to do with the learning rate as I experimented with extremely small values (1e-10, it just took allot longer to get to the point where all the outputs become the same which from my observation is between 22 and 16, in terms of loss)

```
class CTCLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        return y_pred
```

Comment: How can the loss reduce if the output of your model does not change? This does not add up to me.

Comment: @André Thats the thing, maybe it gets closer to the average? The thing is it does not output the exact same thing, it outputs a thing (which is the same no matter the input) no matter the input. So once it does a step of gradient descent, it updates its weights to maybe get closer to the average (and so output it no matter the input)

Comment: Well, how would it do that if it does not change? I have a feeling I don't understand your case completely. Given input data `x`, labels `y`, model `m`, loss `L`: `L(m(x), y)` can only change if either `m(x)` or `y` changes. From your question I understand that `m(x)` is constant for all `x`. Now if `y` changes, e.g. through batch sampling, the loss should not reduce, but fluctuate randomly.  Are you 100% sure your model does not produce different `m(x)` for different `x`? Or am I missing something? :-)

Comment: You got it right, I may have an explanation for your concern, I am running an early stopping callback so when it fluctuates (which weirdly enough 90% of times is in the beginning downwards) it stops it right there before it recovers. FYI: Currently I am training it using dropout for the affected layers and the model has "survived" nearly 10x as long as usually (so 20 epochs instead of 2)

Comment: I just saw the edit you did to your first comment, missed that one completely. Now your explanation makes sense! Regarding the actual problem: Is it possible that your input data has the wrong shape? E.g. swapped batch and time axes or something similar.

Comment: Just to add on to the situation, the dropout thing did not work (so it has nothing to do with overfitting) this is due to me having compared the probabilities (from the last layer, excluding the Ctc one) and not the decoded string. This illusion of success was caused by the randomness that the dropout added, changing the probability of the characters but not the actual results.

Comment: @jr123456jr987654321, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!